# Non standard 1:many relationship in BreezeJS

Tags: breeze

I have 2 Breeze entities which I'm working with that are used in the same UI page that are related yet I can't work out how to define the relationship in the metadata. Currently I'm glueing them together in code but I'm certain there must be a more Breezy way of doing it.

Here's the (shortened) metadata for my entities:

```
{
  "namespace": "Mynamespace",
  "shortName": "SalesInvoice",
  "defaultResourceName": "SalesInvoices",
  "dataProperties": [
    {
      "name": "ID",
      "dataType": "Int32",
      "isPartOfKey": true,
      "isNullable": false,
      "validators": [
        {
          "name": "required"
        },
        {
          "name": "integer"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "InvoiceNumber",
      "dataType": "String",
      "isPartOfKey": false,
      "isNullable": true,
      "validators": [
        {
          "name": "textMedium"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "key": {
    "propertyRef": {
      "name": "ID"
    }
  },
  "autoGeneratedKeyType": "Identity"
},
{
  "namespace": "Mynamespace",
  "shortName": "DocUrl",
  "defaultResourceName": "DocUrls",
  "dataProperties": [
    {
      "name": "ID",
      "dataType": "Int32",
      "isPartOfKey": true,
      "isNullable": false,
      "validators": [
        {
          "name": "required"
        },
        {
          "name": "integer"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Title",
      "dataType": "String",
      "isPartOfKey": false,
      "isNullable": true,
      "validators": [
        {
          "name": "required"
        },
        {
          "name": "textMedium"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Url",
      "dataType": "String",
      "isPartOfKey": false,
      "isNullable": false,
      "validators": [
        {
          "name": "required"
        },
        {
          "name": "url"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Parent",
      "dataType": "String",
      "isPartOfKey": false,
      "isNullable": false,
      "validators": [
        {
          "name": "required"
        },
        {
          "name": "textMedium"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "ParentKey",
      "dataType": "Int32",
      "isPartOfKey": false,
      "isNullable": false,
      "validators": [
        {
          "name": "required"
        },
        {
          "name": "integer"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "key": {
    "propertyRef": {
      "name": "ID"
    }
  },
  "autoGeneratedKeyType": "Identity"
}
```

In the SalesInvoice UI page the user must be able to add any amount of hyperlinks to GoogleDrive documents, which are stored in the DocUrl entity. Normally I would define a SalesInvoiceDocument entity and setup the 1:many relationship in the standard way with a navigation property on SalesInvoice. Now here's the but! The idea of adding hyperlinks is something I need to do for many other entities too. This would lead to creating more entities to store the hyperlinks (eg ProductDocument, CustomerDocument, TransactionDocument, etc), although the fields would always be identical to the DocLink entity.

To avoid this repetition (and preventing from searching documents globally) I've defined the single DocUrl entity with a Parent and ParentKey field. In this case for a new DocUrl entity I set the Parent field to 'SalesInvoice' (or any unique string to define the relationship back to SalesInvoices) and the ParentKey to the ID value of the SalesInvoice.

When I load a SalesInvoice entity I then load it's DocUrl entities with a predicate matching Parent = 'SalesInvoice' and ParentKey = SalesInvoice.ID

This to me looks like a compound key but I've yet to use these in Breeze. If I could define in the navigation property definition to do the Parent = 'SalesInvoice' bit I think that would do the trick, but again not sure how.

So the question is....is there a better way of doing this?

Important point to note: My server backend is custom PHP code, so I'm not working with any .NET environment.

Thanks!